# Improving to class toggling

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, toggle

I am using jQuery 1.6 and I would like to improve the following code (that is, *write less do more*):

```
if (row.hasClass('line_odd')) {
  row.removeClass('line_odd');
  row.addClass('line_even');
} else {
  row.removeClass('line_even');
  row.addClass('line_odd');
}
```

**How can I do that?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming row starts with exactly one of the two classes:

```
row.toggleClass("line_odd line_even")
```

should do the trick.

Comment: This is the way to go given your assumption.

Answer (score 3):

Replace the block with:

```
var hasOdd = row.hasClass('line_odd');
row.toggleClass('line_odd', !hasOdd).toggleClass('line_even', hasOdd);
```

Comment: @Piyush: Having it will avoid calling hasClass twice.

Comment: +1 since it uses the exact same logic as the original and works better when `row` might have neither or both classes set.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest use of something like http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/, for example:

```
row.toggleClass("line_odd")
   .toggleClass("line_even");
```

This assumes that no row element would have both the `line_odd` and `line_even` classes set initially, in order for it to have the same effect as your code.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
var isOdd = row.hasClass('line_odd');
row.toggleClass('line_odd', !isOdd);
row.toggleClass('line_even', isOdd);
```

Comment: @Piyush in an ideal case I would agree. The OP didn't specify that the code started up in the correct state though.  Consider if the row initially started with both 'line_odd' and 'line_even' being present.  In this case `isOdd` is needed.  I agree this is a bit out there but the OP didn't specify and I wanted to make sure my simplification functioned as equally well as the original sample

Answer (score 0):

you can use chaining

```
if (row.hasClass('line_odd')) {
  row.removeClass('line_odd').addClass('line_even');

} else {
  row.removeClass('line_even').addClass('line_odd'); 
}
```

Comment: Ain't the reduced version. Can be reduced further with .toggleClass

Answer (score 0):

```
row.toggleClass('line_odd', row.hasClass('line_odd') ).toggleClass('line_even', 
row.hasClass('line_odd') );
```

This is the reduced version which makes use of [.toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) alongwith the second argument that when true adds the class and if false removes the class.

Comment: Won't this add the classes only when they're _already_ set? `toggleClass` without the second argument already has the right behavior.

Comment: There was a typo in the code which i fixed. About your second statement regarding not needing the second argument - isn't the syntax like $(selector).toggleClass(class,switch)

Comment: That's one possible syntax, yes. Without the second argument, it removes the class if present and adds it if not. You'd also still need to change the first part of you code, to add 'line_odd' only if **'line_even'** is present.